# Incrementally Update Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, ssis, ssas, etl

I have a fact table which has about 27 million records and i am trying to update the fact table so i don't have to fully process the cube every day. The pattern i am following is using look ups to verify whether it an existing record or a new record. I am using SSIS as the etl tool. I am wondering what would be the best way to handle it. Should i load the Source system key from the fact in a cache look up and then compare or try to follow something else.

Any response or help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: With a table of that size, I'd suggest to load new records to a staging table, then have ssis trigger a stored proc to actually do the update.

Comment: Will try that out. Thanks.

Comment: As i will have the create date/update date so was thinking of making my lookup dynamic. Based on the oldest create date, could only pull the values greater then that date. Any thoughts.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, your stored proc would only load from the staging table records where the update date is greater than the max of updatedate in the main table. Sounds good to me.